# SwiftUI List updating from Method

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13

please consider the following swiftUI scenario:

```
List {
  ForEach(manager.items(filter: .all), id: \.id) { item in
    RowView(item: item)
  }
}
```

where `manager` is an environment object injected via `@EnvironmentObject var manager: Manager`. The `items()` method returns an array of core data entities fetched depending on the filter parameter. This works well for mutating elements, but whenever an element is added or removed, the ForEach view is not notified (of course, because its a function return and no "binding" or such).

Whet is the bes practice approach to update the list accordingly? Can I somehow wrap the function call? Or notify about changes? Any tip is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this behaves with core data fetching and how well it performs, but you can try to bind your fetch results like this:

```swift
    //...

    private var items: Binding<[ItemType]> { Binding (
        get: { self.manager.items(filter: .all) },
        set: { _ in }
    )}
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(self.items, id: \.id) { item in
                RowView(item: item)
            }
        }

    //...
```

Or:

```swift
    List {
        ForEach(self.items.wrappedValue, id: \.id) { item in
            RowView(item: item)
        }
    }
```

With Swift 5.3, referencing with `self.` can be omitted.

Comment: I tried something like this first but it doesn't work: Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Binding<[TodoItemEntity]>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'

Comment: I assume adding `.wrappedValue` doesn't make a difference. Perhaps try `ForEach(items.indices) { idx in ;  RowView(item: $items[idx]) }` or `ForEach(Array(items.wrappedValue.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { item in ; RowView(item: item.element) }`. The latter rather if you're not dealing with too many items.

Comment: Adding .wrappedValue does indeed resolve the error. But it still doesn't recognice any changes. How should it? the "get" method of the binding seems to only be fetched once. I think a function cannot be observed for modifications because this would require to execute it frequently and I think this is not how bindings work. If there was a way to programatically trigger a "change" event or such?

Comment: Hm, perhaps you want to try a different approach and move the fetch request directly into the struct then. That seems to be a common practice at least. Maybe you can get some ideas from this discussion: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swift/core-data-relationship-not-updating/1710/1716 I haven't really been playing around enough with Core Data + SwiftUI to pitch you more informed ideas, sorry and good luck!

Comment: yeah sure, it works well if I use @FetchRequest for the items and use that in the foreach. But I do some calculations based on the items in that manager class. This means that I always have to guarantee that the request from the manager class and the request in the view are perfectly in sync (regarding eg. the order and filter predicates) ..

Answer (score -1):

Manager.items should be marked as @Published.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-environmentobject-property-wrapper

Comment: Thx, but It cannot, .items() is a method not a property. As far as I know there is no way to declasre a function as published, the name property-wrapper indicates that too. I modified my questions title to make this even more clear.